# I keep getting this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spotipy'

Tags: python, pip, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to run this code to authenticate with spotify api, but every time I import spotipy, it does't work although when I use pip freeze, I can see that the package is downloaded

```
import os, yaml
from spec import reduce_openapi_spec


with open("openai_openapi.yaml") as f:
    raw_openai_api_spec = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.Loader)
openai_api_spec = reduce_openapi_spec(raw_openai_api_spec)
    
with open("klarna_openapi.yaml") as f:
    raw_klarna_api_spec = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.Loader)
klarna_api_spec = reduce_openapi_spec(raw_klarna_api_spec)

with open("spotify_openapi.yaml") as f:
    raw_spotify_api_spec = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.Loader)
spotify_api_spec = reduce_openapi_spec(raw_spotify_api_spec)


import os
import spotipy
import util
from langchain.requests import RequestsWrapper

os.environ['CLIENT_ID']= ''
os.environ['CLIENT_SECRET']= ''
os.environ['REDIRECT_URI']= ''

def construct_spotify_auth_headers(raw_spec: dict):
    scopes = list(raw_spec['components']['securitySchemes']['oauth_2_0']['flows']['authorizationCode']['scopes'].keys())
    access_token = util.prompt_for_user_token(scope=','.join(scopes))
    return {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }

# Get API credentials.
headers = construct_spotify_auth_headers(raw_spotify_api_spec)
requests_wrapper = RequestsWrapper(headers=headers)
```

I made sure I'm using last version of spotipy, downloading it using pip and pip3, made sure no other file is called spotipy in the working directory

Comment: Looks like spotipy is not used in the example you provided, hence I can't reproduce the error. Also, would you please give us the full error trace?

Answer (score 0):

You must install the dependencies. In this case, you need to install the "spotipy" package.

```
pip install spotipy==2.23.0
```

If the correct package is already installed. Then please make sure that correct interpreter is selected in your IDE. If your terminal shows the correct python interpreter, then same must be used by IDE.

For ex: In VS Code, you can select the interpreter to be used. Do a quick google search on how to do it.